# How to keep PEP8 rule for max 79 characters

Tags: python

I have this code

```
elif key == "valid":
   print _("You should enter only one character from the alphabet without repeating it")
```

and it is more than 79 charqcters which is against PEP8. I am trying to figure it out how to fit the code before this 79th character. The problem is that I have a localization on this print and if I divided it into 2 separate strings:

```
elif key == "valid":
    print _("You should enter only one character from"
            "the alphabet without repeating it")
```

this breaks the localization. I am looking for a different way to achieve this.

Comment: What tool are you using to extract the strings?

Comment: this is an obsolete rule, when was the last time you used an `80` column TTY terminal as your primary coding environment? `1920X1080` screens make this an anachronism at best it isn't `2001` anymore, and I question the validity of this *rule* in 2001 as well.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson: PEP 8 isn't meant to be adhered to blindly (and it says so right in the PEP itself). It also isn't etched in stone for all eternity. It does get updated from time to time. The fact that the 79-column recommendation is still in the PEP means that it is still recommended. There are good reasons to keep lines shorter regardless of whether we have the capacity to display longer ones. There are also good reasons to use longer lines. The recommendation is not obsolete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt to split the string across two lines changed the string, because you lost the space between `from` and `the`. Try this:

```
elif key == "valid":
    # Note the trailing space after 'from'
    print _("You should enter only one character from "
            "the alphabet without repeating it")
```

When using implicit string joining, `"a""b"` is equivalent to `"ab"`, not `"a b"`.

Comment: Geat! Thanks for that hint it was very helpfull!

Comment: @user3437668: If it's useful, then upvote it. Also, if it completely solves your problem and there are no better answers, accept it. (You should generally wait a while for a few answers to show up before choosing one as accepted; however, in this case, it's hard to imagine what else someone could say that would improve upon what chepner has already said.)